# Plotly.py: fill to zero, different color for positive/negative

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

With Plotly, I can easily plot a single lines and fill the area between the line and `y == 0`:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[-2, -1.5, 1, 2.5],
    fill='tozeroy',
    mode='lines',
))
fig.show()
```

[image]

How can I split the filled area in two? In particular, filling with red where `y < 0` and with green where `y > 0`.

I would like to maintain the line as continuous. That means, I am not interested in just drawing two separate filled polygons.

Note that the line does not necessarily have values at `y == 0`.

Comment: Maybe related, although they are different questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421334/plotly-py-fill-between-lines-different-color-por-positive-negative

Comment: If you draw separate polygons, the line would still be continuous as long as they end and start at the same point.

Comment: @user3483203 Only in appearance, right? That means, if I want to show the legend, I would have two legends for the two polygons, while I want to have only one, for the single line. Also, I would like to have a single "hover" display.

Answer (score 2):

I was in need of such a graph so I wrote a function.

```
def resid_fig(resid, tickvalues):
    """
    resid:      The y-axis points to be plotted. x-axis is assumed to be linearly increasing
    tickvalues: The values you want to be displayed as ticklabels on x-axis. Works for hoverlabels too. Has to be
                same length as `resid`. (This is necessary to ignore 'gaps' in graph where two polygons meet.)
    """
    #Adjusting array with paddings to connect polygons at zero line on x-axis
    index_array = []
    start_digit = 0
    split_array = np.split(resid,np.where(np.abs(np.diff(np.sign(resid)))==2)[0]+1)
    split_array = [np.append(x,0) for x in split_array]
    split_array = [np.insert(x,0,0) for x in split_array]
    split_array[0] = np.delete(split_array[0],0)
    split_array[-1] = np.delete(split_array[-1],-1)
    for x in split_array:
        index_array.append(np.arange(start_digit,start_digit+len(x)))
        start_digit += len(x)-1
        
    #Making an array for ticklabels
    flat = []
    for x in index_array:
        for y in x:
            flat.append(y)
    flat_counter = Counter(flat)
    none_indices = np.where([(flat_counter[x]>1) for x in flat_counter])[0]
    custom_tickdata = []
    neg_padding = 0
    start_pos = 0
    for y in range(len(flat)):
        for x in range(start_pos,flat[-1]+1):
            if x in none_indices:
                custom_tickdata.append('')
                break
            custom_tickdata.append(tickvalues[x-neg_padding])
        neg_padding +=1
        start_pos = 1+x

    #Making an array for hoverlabels
    custom_hoverdata=[]
    sublist = []
    for x in custom_tickdata:
        if x == '':
            custom_hoverdata.append(sublist)
            sublist = []
            sublist.append(x)
            continue
        sublist.append(x)
        sublist2 = sublist.copy()
    custom_hoverdata.append(sublist2)
    
    #Creating figure
    fig = go.Figure()
    idx = 0
    for x,y in zip(split_array,index_array):
        color = 'rgba(219,43,57,0.8)' if x[1]<0 else 'rgba(47,191,113,0.8)'
        if (idx==0 and x[0] < 0):
            color= 'rgba(219,43,57,0.8)'
        fig.add_scatter(y=x, x=y, fill='tozeroy', fillcolor=color, line_color=color, customdata=custom_hoverdata[idx],
                        hovertemplate='%{customdata}<extra></extra>',legendgroup='mytrace',
                       showlegend=False if idx>0 else True)
        idx += 1
    fig.update_layout()
    fig.update_xaxes(tickformat='', hoverformat='',tickmode = 'array',
                tickvals = np.arange(index_array[-1][-1]+1),
                ticktext = custom_tickdata)
    fig.update_traces(mode='lines')
    fig.show()
```

### Example-

```
resid_fig([-2,-5,7,11,3,2,-1,1,-1,1], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

[image]

Now, for the caveats-

1. It does use separate polygons but I have combined all the traces into a single `legendgroup` so clicking on legend turns all of them on or off. About the legend colour, one way is to change `0` to `1` in `showlegend=False if idx>0` in the `fig.add_scatter()` call. It then shows two legends, red and green still in the same legendgroup though so they still turn on and off together.
2. The function works by first separating continuous positive and negative values into arrays, adding `0` to the end and start of each array so the polygons can meet at the x-axis. This means the figure does not scale as well but depending on the use-case, it might not matter as much. This does not affect the hoverlabels or ticklabels as they are blank on these converging points.
3. The most important one, the graph does not work as intended when any of the point in the passed array is `0`. I'm sure it can be modified to work for it but I have no use for it and the question doesn't ask for it either.